# How to draw lines dynamically on SVG Picture?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to develop an `Attack Map` when basically like all maps it will show the "Attacks" that are happening over the world but basically it will be randomly as I don't have access to any `AV's` `APIs` to get correct data. As of now I only have this `SVG map` shown on my HTML page:
[image]

And I'd want to draw some lines from one country to another to simulate the attacks. I have been searching about this and I have seen two "solutions". One is a `JS` code that draws a line in `HTML`:

```
    if (stroke){
        ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
    }

    if (width){
        ctx.lineWidth = width;
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(...begin);
    ctx.lineTo(...end);
    ctx.stroke();

}

const canvas = document.querySelector("#line");
if(canvas.getContext){
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    drawLine(ctx, [100, 100], [300, 100], 'green', 5)
}
```

but as I said this draws a line outside of the `SVG map` and inside of HTML. I also saw a `line` tag which can be placed inside of `SVG` tags but it is static. I want to be dynamic and simulate the attacks. Is there any way I can do this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Since the map you are using is already an SVG, I would suggest to learn manipulating SVG images. It's similar to HTML. You can create SVG elements inside your JS script by using `.createElementNS()` with the correct namespace. Then you can just edit the svg elements you created as if they're HTML tags. So you can set the attributes dynamically and append the svg line element to the SVG map. If you want to stick to canvas, look for a good way to overlap the canvas and the svg image and code a function to translate the coordinates between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the SVG element is static, you can add `<line />` elements dynamically when the DOM has loaded:

```js
const lines = [
  {
    from: { x: 0, y: 20 },
    to: { x: 30, y: 60 }
  },
  {
    from: { x: 0, y: 20 },
    to: { x: 30, y: 60 }
  }
];

function addLine (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
  
  line.setAttribute("x1", x1);
  line.setAttribute("y1", y1);
  line.setAttribute("x2", x2);
  line.setAttribute("y2", y2);
  line.setAttribute("stroke", "white");
  
  document.getElementById("mySvg").appendChild(line);
}

addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  for (const line of lines) {
    addLine(line.from.x, line.from.y, line.to.x, line.to.y);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice bro, thanks for this. It worked as intended. Although I have a question, can I animate it? Or I could open a different topic about this?

Comment: Please have a look at the `<animate />` element, which is also part of the SVG spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate

Comment: I mean I wanna animate the lines and `<animate />` tag is not working... Tried in js: `line.animate(200, mina.easein)` but this removes lines from the svg